# Suppress Comment in SQL Generation MySQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL workbench can export a MYSQL data model to SQL create table script. But can I choose to suppress comments when doing the export? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you no integrated tool.
You could run it through ***sed***.
The following command can do the trick:

```
sed '/^COMMENT/ d' original.sql > cleaned.sql
```

*(Well... obviously you need sed for this...)*

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Server->Data export->Advanced options->SQL`
2. scroll to bottom
3. Un-check "comments"

Comment: I Cannot find the option